# Fourier transform

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I find some problems about pde, I guess, concerning Distribution solution.

Define $$<T,\phi> = \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{|x|\geq \epsilon} \frac{\phi(x)}{x} dx.$$ Then $$ \mathcal{F}({T})(t) = -i \ \mbox{sgn} (t),$$ where $\mathcal{F}(T)$ is the Fourier transform of $T$.

That $<\cdot, \cdot>$ always involving ssomething related to distributional sence of solution of pde. I am not quite understand about it. How should I prove this statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is called the Hilberttransform. It is a straight forward calculation:
$$\langle \hat{T}, \varphi \rangle = \langle T, \hat{\varphi} \rangle = \frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\lvert \xi \rvert \geq \varepsilon} \frac{1}{\xi} \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi(x) e^{-ix\xi} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}\xi.$$
There you have to use Fubini and write $e^{-ix\xi} = \cos(-x\xi) + i \sin(-x \xi)$. The integral with $\cos$ vanishes cause of the symmetry of $\frac{\cos(-x\xi)}{\xi}$. The rest follows with
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(bx)}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \pi sgn(b).$$